# How can I create a drop down menu on checkbox click?

Tags: javascript

Here are my checkboxes and drop down:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Castle Connolly Regional Top Doctor" />Castle Connolly Regional Top Doctor</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor" id="ccn" />Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Vitals Compassionate Doctor" />Vital's Compassionate Doctor Recognition</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Super Doctor" />Super Doctor</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
```

I was initially trying to capture them both in arrays and concatenate then together into a variable that I insert in a database, but it's difficult if the arrays aren't the same length. I thought it would be best to only have a drop down when one of the boxes are selected, so how can I do so in JavaScript?

Comment: go through this: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/if-checkbox-checked-show-dropdown-menu/3115/2

Comment: So, the user checks a checkbox and then what should happen? Can you explain the interactions step-by-step, and what should happen? What precise result do you want to get? Have you attempted to code this yourself, can you please show your code (so that we can get a feel of what you are/were trying to do, *and* so we can help point out the errors or improvements to help you learn)?

Comment: Similar to what's done on this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cB9FC/1/    I want to have checkboxes with a corresponding dropdown that when clicked will enable the drop down. Any box that is not checked the drop down should not be posted so the array lengths will be the same and I can concat them together easier ..

Comment: I think this jfiddle actually solved it, I guess I'll just do it by id for all the boxes though I didn't want to have so many scripts doing the same thing ..

Comment: Here's a fiddle where I changed the ids to numbers and am trying to use a loop to iterate through ids, all i changed was the two ids and not working, what is wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/cB9FC/119/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this with jQuery is, I think:

```
// select the <input> elements whose 'type' attribute is equal
// to 'checkbox', and bind the anonymous function of the on()
// method as the event handler for the named ('change') event(s):
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){

  // find the first ancestor <label> element of the current
  // <input>, find the next sibling that matches the selector
  // (to ensure that we're working only with <select> elements,
  // and set its 'disabled' property to false when the the
  // checkbox is checked (so !true) and to true when the checkbox
  // is not checked:
  $(this).closest('label').next('select').prop('disabled', !this.checked);

// fire the change event on each of the checkboxes on page-load,
// to appropriately disable/enable the <select> elements:
}).change();
```

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('label').next('select').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
}).change();
```

```css
label {
  margin: 0.5em 1em 0 0;
}
label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Castle Connolly Regional Top Doctor" />Castle Connolly Regional Top Doctor</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor" id="ccn" />Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Vitals Compassionate Doctor" />Vital's Compassionate Doctor Recognition</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value="Super Doctor" />Super Doctor</label>
<select name="check_year[]"></select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b4uqun7d/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Thanks this worked. Now, if the drop down is disabled, will it be posted?

Comment: Posted to the server you mean? No, per the specs an 'unsuccessful' (disabled or un-checked) form-element (meaning `<select>`, `<input>`, `<input type="checkbox">` in this case) will not be sent to the server. Did you want it to be?

Comment: No, I just wanted to be sure it wasn't posted so the two arrays will be the same length and I could use some easier methods to concat the values together

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri) by someone else.

1. Basically you create a div with an un-ordered list

   ```
            <div class="mutliSelect">
               <ul>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson"     />Sony Ericson</li>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
   ```
2. Then you have a listener function that do something when the user clicks on one of the check boxes

   ```
     $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
           // do something here
     })
   ```

There is a lot of detail in the codepen. You might not need all of it.

Thanks,

Paras